# USB connection with my android not working any longer

Tags: usb, huawei, usb-connection-mode

I have a problem connecting my android phone with my PC. I however get the option of **Transfer files** under **Use USB for** but this does not seem work. Any leads?

Comment: Check different USB cable and different USB port on your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I have tried phones and different cables(Type C and the normal USB)

Comment: you get *Use USB for* popup when connecting?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mtp+usb+device+bug